# Form submission keeps failing in Django Tutorial

Tags: python, django

I am on the [Django tutorial (part 4)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial04/) and trying to create a form which allows user to choose answer to a poll. The questions load properly, however when I click 'vote' (ie select option and submit form) the following error keeps showing:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/polls/vote/6
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^polls/ ^$ [name='index']
^polls/ ^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$ [name='detail']
^polls/ ^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results/$ [name='results']
^polls/ ^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$ [name='vote']
^admin/
The current URL, polls/vote/6, didn't match any of these.
```

Here is the code from detail.html which has the form:

```
{{ poll.question }}

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="/polls/vote/{{ poll.id }} " method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in poll.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id     }}" />
<label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

I suspect the problem is in the line `<form action="/polls/vote/{{ poll.id }} " method="post">` but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the url to /polls/{{poll.id}}/vote/

Comment: yeah...this happens all the time :)

Answer (score 6):

You have your poll id and `vote` action reversed.

Your url pattern is of the form:

```
^polls/ ^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$ [name='vote']
```

but your form action points to `vote/id` instead. Reverse those:

```
<form action="/polls/{{ poll.id }}/vote" method="post">
```

Note that the tutorial actually uses a different method to generate that URL; it uses:

```
<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' poll.id %}" method="post">
```

where the [`url` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#url) generates the correct URL for you, given the `polls:vote` route configuration and the id of the current poll object (`poll.id`).

Using `{% url routename arguments %}` makes it easier for you to later change your routes, without having to then correct all your templates too.

Comment: Thanks Martijn. I had tried using the namespacing but didn't seem to work so I hardcoded in the url instead.

Answer (score 0):

in the previous tut03 they have removed the hard-coded part of the url
now it is `<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">`

this should work